# Create a table with latex3: error extra alignment tab

Tags: tables, latex3

I would like to create a table with a macro. Unfortunately, I get an error. So here is
a simple example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
 
\begin{document} 
 
\ExplSyntaxOn 
 
%%% Create a new table nxn 
%%% First parameter: number of lines and columns 
%%% Second parameter: entries of the table 
\NewDocumentCommand{\TableCreate}{mm}{ 
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {1} 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline 
        \int_do_until:nNnn {\l_tmpa_int} > {#1} 
        { 
            %%% Test if this the last column of the line 
            \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int} = {#1} 
            { 
                %%% This is the last colum 
                \clist_item:nn {#2} {\l_tmpa_int} & \\ \hline 
            } 
            { 
                %%% This is not the last column 
                \clist_item:nn {#2} {\l_tmpa_int}  & 
            } 
        } 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
} 
 
\ExplSyntaxOff 
 
    \TableCreate{4}{1,2,3,4} 

\end{document}
```

Here I have a macro `TableCreate{4}{1,2,3,4}`. I would like to create a table
with one line and four columns. When I want to write something in a cell, I have to
test if it's the last column. That's the reason why I use

```
\int_do_until:nNnn {\l_tmpa_int} > {#1}
```

I use the variable `\l_tmpa_int` to iterate over the columns.
I use the first argument of the macro to know how many columns I have. Later I want to create tablesin which the number of columns is not the same as the number of lines. When I compile this code, I get:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 
                             
l.33    \TableCreate{4}{1,2,3,4}
```

I don't understand why I get this error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `&` ends the current group (and the internal state of the loop you are in). You need to build up the whole row in a `tl` and then use it (or at least, that's the easiest way)

Answer (score 2):

As David told you, you're facing problems with the groups (and you're missing the `\int_incr:N` to actually step through your `clist`). The minimum-change variant from your code would be to simply use a global instead of a local int variable. Note that I put the `\int_gincr:N` call in front of each cell and used `-1` to compensate for this. This is necessary, because if you put it after `\\ \hline` you end up with unexpandable material in the first cell of the second row and get a second row in the output.

Also, instead of using a hardcoded number of 4 columns the following code uses `*{#1}{c|}` to get exactly as many columns as needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_LucArmand_tmp_int
%%% Create a new table nxn
%%% First parameter: number of lines and columns
%%% Second parameter: entries of the table
\NewDocumentCommand \TableCreate { m m }
  {
    \int_gset_eq:NN \g_LucArmand_tmp_int \c_one_int
    \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
      \hline
      \int_do_until:nNnn {\g_LucArmand_tmp_int} > {#1}
        {
          \int_gincr:N \g_LucArmand_tmp_int
          \clist_item:nn {#2} { \g_LucArmand_tmp_int - 1 }
          %%% Test if this the last column of the line
          \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_LucArmand_tmp_int - 1 } = {#1}
            { %%% This is the last column
              \\ \hline
            }
            { %%% This is not the last column
              &
            }
        }
    \end{tabular}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TableCreate{4}{1,2,3,4}

\end{document}
```

But we can even further improve this. Why the need to specify the number of elements, we can just let TeX do the counting for us (this uses an optional argument to default to the count of the `clist`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_LucArmand_tmp_int
%%% Create a new table nxn
%%% First parameter: number of lines and columns
%%% Second parameter: entries of the table
\NewDocumentCommand \TableCreate { O{\clist_count:n{#2}} m }
  {
    \int_gset_eq:NN \g_LucArmand_tmp_int \c_one_int
    \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
      \hline
      \int_do_until:nNnn {\g_LucArmand_tmp_int} > {#1}
        {
          \int_gincr:N \g_LucArmand_tmp_int
          \clist_item:nn {#2} { \g_LucArmand_tmp_int - 1 }
          %%% Test if this the last column of the line
          \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_LucArmand_tmp_int - 1 } = {#1}
            { %%% This is the last column
              \\ \hline
            }
            { %%% This is not the last column
              &
            }
        }
    \end{tabular}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TableCreate[3]{1,2,3,4}

\end{document}
```

But neither the first nor the second code implements the behaviour you specified in your documenting comment (number of lines **and** columns), for this the easiest solution code wise would be to add an `\int_mod:nn` call:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_LucArmand_tmp_int
%%% Create a new table nxn
%%% First parameter: number of lines and columns
%%% Second parameter: entries of the table
\NewDocumentCommand \TableCreate { O{\clist_count:n{#2}} m }
  {
    \int_gset_eq:NN \g_LucArmand_tmp_int \c_one_int
    \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
      \hline
      \int_do_until:nNnn {\g_LucArmand_tmp_int} > { \clist_count:n {#2} }
        {
          \int_gincr:N \g_LucArmand_tmp_int
          \clist_item:nn {#2} { \g_LucArmand_tmp_int - 1 }
          %%% Test if this the last column of the line
          \int_compare:nNnTF
            { \int_mod:nn { \g_LucArmand_tmp_int - 1 } {#1} } = \c_zero_int
            { %%% This is the last column
              \\ \hline
            }
            { %%% This is not the last column
              &
            }
        }
    \end{tabular}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TableCreate[2]{1,2,3,4}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer has provided good reasons and good code for the job, but there's a slicker way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_cols_int
\seq_new:N \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq

%%% First parameter: number of lines and columns
%%% Second parameter: entries of the table
\NewDocumentCommand \TableCreate { O{\clist_count:n{#2}} m }
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_cols_int { #1 }
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq { #2 }
    \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
      \hline
      \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq \__lucarmand_tablecreate:nn
    \end{tabular}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lucarmand_tablecreate:nn
  {
    #2 % the entry
    \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_cols_int } == 0 }
      {% end of row
        \\ \hline
      }
      {% still columns to go
        &
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TableCreate[2]{1,2,3,4}
\TableCreate[4]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l}

\end{document}
```

The body of the table is created in one swoop, with `\\\hline` inserted when the index is a multiple of the number of columns, otherwise `&` is appended.

[image]

We can also add a check that the number of items is a multiple of the number of columns; here the remedy is to add `?` items.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_cols_int
\seq_new:N \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq

%%% First parameter: number of lines and columns
%%% Second parameter: entries of the table
\NewDocumentCommand \TableCreate { O{\clist_count:n{#2}} m }
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_cols_int { #1 }
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq { #2 }
    \int_compare:nF
      {% is the number of items a multiple of #1?
       \int_mod:nn { \seq_count:N \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq } { #1 } == 0
      }
      {% no! Add entries
       \prg_replicate:nn
         {% add the necessary
           #1 - \int_mod:nn { \seq_count:N \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq } { #1 } 
         }
         {% blank entries
          \seq_put_right:Nn \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq { ? }
         }
      }
    \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
      \hline
      \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_body_seq \__lucarmand_tablecreate:nn
    \end{tabular}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lucarmand_tablecreate:nn
  {
    #2 % the entry
    \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { \l__lucarmand_tablecreate_cols_int } == 0 }
      {% end of row
        \\ \hline
      }
      {% still columns to go
        &
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TableCreate[2]{1,2,3,4}
\TableCreate[4]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l}

\bigskip

\TableCreate[4]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m}

\end{document}
```

[image]